# C++ code distribution: faulting module ntdll.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, qt5.3, ntdll

I built a c++ win32 console app using VisualStudio 2013 on a windows 8 machine. It was running smoothly on my laptop. Yet, when I tried the distribution version on another windows 8 laptop, myproj.exe file crashed. Having looked at the "Event Viewer" I found:

```
Faulting module name:ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17278
Exception code: 0Xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x003d190
Faulting process id: 0x1c64
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Desktop\Dist\myproj.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

So, I started installing VisualStudio Express and Qt5 on the second machine to compile my code on it. Before starting a new build, I tried myproj.exe and surprisingly it worked just fine. Searching different forums has not helped so far. I really appreciate any hint for potential reasons before distributing my code.

Comment: Are you using avast or some other antivirus that runs unknown programs in a sandbox the first time?

Comment: @drescherjm: Yes, not on the development machine but on the second one. how come?